# Верстка. Отображение сайта на экранах разного размера

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть сайт, который адаптивен под экраны шириной от `1200px` до `1920px`, сделано это с помощью бутстрапа(`col-lg-№`). Как сделать так, чтобы на всех экранах шириной меньше `1200px` все отображалось с горизонтальным скролом, а не сжималось и наезжало друг на друга?
И можно ли сделать так, чтобы при ширине меньше `1200px` был не горизонтальный скролл, а уменьшенный масштаб сайта (например для мобильных устройств)?
Про медиа запросы слышал, что можно сделать разные версии для разной ширины экрана тоже вкурсе, но сейчас время поджимает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`И можно ли сделать так, чтобы при ширине меньше 1200px был не горизонтальный скролл, а уменьшенный масштаб сайта (например для мобильных устройств)?`

Можно для тега `<body>` задать минимальную ширину, к примеру `min-width: 1200px;` и тогда сайт будет уменьшаться без горизонтальной линии.

А вообще, делайте качественный продукт, без костылей и прочих...
Предупреждайте, договаривайтесь с заказчиком чтобы прикрутить адаптивность на сайт. Вам будет польза и пользователи будут довольны =)

Comment: Благодарю, приму ваш совет и буду стараться делать качественно и в срок!